# DataTableとlinqについて

Tags: c#, sql, linq

お世話になってます。

```
            string cmdQuery = "SELECT *  FROM TableA";
            using (DataTable TableA = new DataTable())
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdQuery, conn))
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comd)) {

                adapter.Fill(TableA);
                var test = from a in TableA
                          group a by new { a.ID, a.Date, a.No } into g
                          select new { 
                          id = a.ID
                          DAte = a.Date
                          };
            }
```

取得したtableAをlinqでグループ化したいと考えてたのですが、dataTableのクエリ　パターンの実装が見つかりませんでした。"groupeby"が見つかりません。と言われてしまいます。
回避方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

型指定のされていない`DataTable`に対してLINQを使用する場合は、`System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`を参照して[`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.100).aspx)メソッドと[`DataRowExtensions.Field<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.data.datarowextensions(v=vs.100).aspx)メソッドを使用します。

```
from a in TableA.AsEnumerable()
group a by new {
    ID = a.Field<string>("ID"),
    Date = a.Field<string>("Date"),
    No = a.Field<string>("No")
}
```

Comment: @pgrhoさん　勉強になります。ありがとうございます。